# How to scroll TextView in a Widget?

Tags: android, scroll, textview, android-widget

This is my widget.xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widgetLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#80DDDDDD">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgetText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#a9010101"
    android:textSize="15sp"/> </RelativeLayout>
```

I've try with

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

But the widget still not scroll. Whereas that the scrollView is not supported in a widget, how can i do it?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking.. Could you be more clear?

Comment: Are you using a vertically scrollable widget?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh i have got a widget formated by a textview. Inside the textView there could be more lines of text. If the widget size is small, i can't see all text rows so i want scroll it to show all the content.

Comment: @Adi what do you mean?

Comment: Widgets can contain listviews (for example), which would allow the user to scroll. This means that the textview can be as big as you want, since the user can scroll down. If nothing else works, I suppose you might want to put in a listview in the widget to with just the one textview. Not the best, but I don't believe there is another solution.

Comment: Have you tried with NestedScrollView (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) instead of ScrollView?

Comment: @LeonardoRignanese You could just wrap the `TextView` in a `ScrollView`, right?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh I would scroll the textView inside the widget. I have a lot of widget that allows you to do it. I would know how they do it.